# Ler cada linha de um arquivo com tipos diferentes em c usando vetor

Tags: c

Boa tarde, eu preciso criar um código em C que funciona da seguinte maneira:

Lê um arquivo .dat que a primeira coluna é a pista, a segunda a quantidade de palavras dessa pista, e as colunas seguintes são as palavras. Cada linha é uma pista diferente, com palavras diferentes que podem ter até 3 posições.

Eu devo criar uma variável pista, int para a quantidade e um vetor com 3 posições. Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 char url[]="PALAVRAS.dat", pista[17], vetpalavras[3][17];
 int qtd, i;
 FILE *arq;

 arq = fopen(url, "r");
 if(arq == NULL)
   printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
 else
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  if ( (fscanf(arq,"%s %d %s %s %s\n", pista, &qtd, vetpalavras[1],vetpalavras[2],vetpalavras[3]))==1 )
   printf("%s %d %s %s %s\n",  pista, qtd, vetpalavras[1],vetpalavras[2],vetpalavras[3]);
}
 fclose(arq);

 return 0;
}
```

Arquivo .dat é o seguinte:

```
Vegetal 2 ACELGA ALFACE
Automovel 3 MOTOR EMBREAGEM ESCAPAMENTO
Cozinha 3 PRATO PANELA FOGAO
Reptil 1 JARARACA
Mamifero 2 BALEIA MACACO
```

A minha dúvida é: eu estou usando a função certa (fscanf) para fazer isso? eu estou tentando mas como cada linha tem uma quantidade de palavras diferentes não está dando certo. E também por algum motivo o código ta ignorando o \n.

Eu preciso achar uma forma de enumerar cada linha para depois poder sortear as palavras.

Desculpe se é algo muito grande, mas estou realmente quebrando a cabeça nisso. Alguém tem uma ideia de pelo menos o que posso fazer em alguma parte desse desafio?

Comment: Você faz um loop variando i de 0 até 4 mas cada leitura sobrescreve os dados da leitura anterior. Além disso utiliza índices de 1 até 3 para vetpalavras quando deveria ser de 0 até 2.

Comment: Além disso uma execução bem sucedida de fscanf retornará a quantidade de itens lidos, no caso 5 e não 1.

Comment: mas se eu uso o vetor como i eu não sei como eu poderia armazenar as 3 strings diferentes sendo que são 3 strings diferentes para as 5 linhas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você lê o nome da "pista", e a quantidade de palavras.
Depois você lê as palavras, uma de cada vez.

```
#include <stdio.h> // exit
#include <stdlib.h> // exit

int main(void)
{
  int qtd, i;
  char url[] = "palavras.dat", pista[17], vetpalavras[3][17];

  printf("*\n");

  FILE *arq = fopen(url, "r");
  if (arq == NULL)
  {
    printf("* erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    printf("*\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (;;)
  {
    // primeiro faz a leitura do nome e da quantidade de palavras
    if (fscanf(arq,"%16s %d", pista, &qtd) != 2)
    {
      // nao conseguiu ler os 2 campos

      // e' fim de arquivo ?
      if (feof(arq))
        printf("* ok, fim de arquivo\n");
      else
        printf("* erro no conteudo do arquivo\n");

      printf("*");
      exit(0);
    }

    // neste ponto leu o nome e a quantidade de palavras

    // agora vai ler as palavras

    if (qtd > 3)
      qtd = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
    {
      if (fscanf(arq, "%16s", vetpalavras[i]) != 1)
      {
        printf("* erro no conteudo do arquivo\n");
        printf("*\n");
        exit(2);
      }
    }

    // ok, leu as palavras

    printf("* nome=%-10s qtd=%d", pista, qtd);

    for (i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
      printf(" %s", vetpalavras[i]);

    printf("\n");
  }

  fclose(arq);
}
```

Teste:

```
$./390144
*
* nome=Vegetal    qtd=2 ACELGA ALFACE
* nome=Automovel  qtd=3 MOTOR EMBREAGEM ESCAPAMENTO
* nome=Cozinha    qtd=3 PRATO PANELA FOGAO
* nome=Reptil     qtd=1 JARARACA
* nome=Mamifero   qtd=2 BALEIA MACACO
* ok, fim de arquivo
*
$
```

Comment: como eu seleciono uma linha individualmente? não estou conseguindo pois parece que a variável pista é sobrescrita e só consigo pegar a última linha

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta

Comment: estou fazendo o jogo do roda a roda, e eu preciso fazer um sorteio para selecionar uma dessas pistas e depois imprimi-la junto com as palavras associadas à ela. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso pq não to conseguindo pegar linha por linha. Por exemplo: o programa faz o sorteio desse arquivo dat e seleciona apenas uma linha, dps imprime a pista e as palavras dessa linha.

Comment: (1) declare uma struct X com os campos pista, qtd e vetpalavras (2) crie um array de structs X (3) a cada linha lida, guarde no array de structs
(ps. X é só um nome ilustrativo, escolha um nome adequado)

Comment: está dando esse erro: "request for member 'qtd' in something not a structure or union". em que lugar do código eu coloco os campos do struct para guardar?

Comment: abra uma nova pergunta com as alterações que você fez

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390167/assignment-to-expression-with-array-type-em-uma-struct-com-matrix